# Changing background color and text color on refresh

Tags: javascript, css, background-color

I'm working with a site that changes the background color of a div randomly when refreshed.
I have a working code for that:

```
var bgcolorlist = ['#FFFFFF', '#000000', '#298ACC', '#B079E0'];

$(function() {
$('#color-change').css({
        background: bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)]
        color: bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)]
});
});
```

The problem is that I am trying to change text-color also to match the current background color. However now with my current code, both of the background and the text-color change randomly. How can I fix that only the background-color of the div changes randomly and the text-color would just copy the current color of the div?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create another list for the text colors and fill it by appropriate colors. Below is a list with sample colors:

```
var textColorList = ['#000000', '#ffffff', '#00ff00', '#ff0000'];
var bgcolorlist = ['#FFFFFF', '#000000', '#298ACC', '#B079E0'];

$(function() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)
  $('#color-change').css({         
    background: bgcolorlist[randomNumber]
    color: textColorList[randomNumber]
  });
});
```

Comment: why did you declared `randomNumber` inside the `css` method ?

Comment: @kapreski Thanks! what a horrible mistake I did!! I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var bgcolorlist = ['#FECE1B', '#F1585D', '#3BC2D6', '#A5CE39'];

$(function() {
  var backgroundColor = bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)];
  $('#color-change').css({
        background: backgroundColor 
        color: backgroundColor 
  });
});
```

How about extract random color out site of the css function?

Comment: and we will see nothing ... (text color = background color)